# How do I use java library in es6 version of javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, ecmascript-6, nashorn, j2v8

I want to use a java library in a javascript written in ES6. I tried j2v8 and nashorn, but they are not supporting ES6 features. Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your ES6 code down to ES5, maybe?

Comment: Do you have to use this Java library? You can try using JS equivalents.

Comment: @JoeClay I am following this method now

Comment: @SuperStormer, Yeah.. I have to use this java library

Comment: Have you looked at Rhino? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent builds of J2V8 (4.7.1) is built with V8 5.4.500.45. I'm not sure what ES 6 features V8 5.4.500.45, but J2V8 will be "bug for bug" / "feature for feature" compatible with that.

J2V8 is just a wrapper around V8, so it only supports as much or as little as V8 does.